# Basement shower drain backing up when washing machine runs

Tags: basement, shower, drain, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

When running washing machine, water backs up through a nearby shower drain and makes a gurgling noise. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You likely have a partial blockage down the line from these two drains, or maybe where the two lines are joined.  First thing to try would be a long snake to see if you can clear the line from either of your drains.+

Comment: This is really common and usually a partial blockage as Bmitch suggests, some rare cases heavily corroded pipes can cause backups because of turblance but in this case they are close to failure. A snake to clean will be your friend.